# How to check if an integer is some root?

Tags: c, primes

```
int intpow(int b, int e)
{
    int r;
    if(e==0) return 1;
    if(e==1) return b;
    r = intpow(b, e/2);
    return r*r*((e&1)?b:1);
}

int check_perfect_power(int n)
{
    int p, i;
    for(p=sizeof(int)*8;p>2;p--)
    {
        for(i=2;intpow(i,p) <= n;i++)
        {
            if(intpow(i,p)==n) return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I want to check if an integer greater than 0 is a square, cube, etc....

and return the lowest root.

For example:

`64 = 2^6 = 4^3 = 8^2`

`check_perfect_power(64)` should return 2 (from 2^6).

Comment: And what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: @klutt it makes perfect sense but for some reason its not producing an output im expecting

Comment: What does `check_perfect_power(2147483647)` return? What should it return?

Comment: @n.m. thats a really big number so its taking some time

Comment: Update your question so that it is clear.

Comment: It does: https://ideone.com/ZknbsB

Comment: well if this takes you longer than a couple of minutes you know your method is terribly inefficient.

Comment: @user3386109 No, because the smallest root must have the greater exponent. OP's code seems [almost correct](https://ideone.com/gpUKhQ) to me. It may be more efficient, of course, and it should consider the limited range of `int` though.

Comment: I wonder if `sizeof(int)` does what you think it does.